# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

```
import socket

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5200

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connecting to remote computer 80
server_address = (IP,PORT)
sock.connect(server_address)
# Sending data to server


x = input('enter firstname:')
sock.send(x)
y = input("enter lastname:")
sock.send(y)

server_msg = sock.recv(1024)
print (server_msg)


# Closing the socket
sock.close()
```

when I run the code it I get this error " a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' " ,any idea how to solve it?
and i get this error when i'm typing the first name.

Answer (score 4):

`input()` returns a string, but `send()` requires bytes. You need to encode the strings:

```
x = input('enter firstname:')
sock.send(x.encode("utf-8"))
y = input("enter lastname:")
sock.send(y.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the code (make sure you have installed the sockData module):

```
import socket
import sockData

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5200

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connecting to remote computer 80
server_address = (IP,PORT)
sock.connect(server_address)
# Sending data to server


x = input('enter firstname:')
sockData.send.sendData(sock, x)
y = input("enter lastname:")
sockData.send.sendData(sock, y)

server_msg = sockData.receive.recvData(sock, 1024)
print (server_msg)


# Closing the socket
sock.close()
```